# Vim as Python IDE on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, vim, vi

I use vim for basic text editing but now I want to use as Python IDE. I don't know where to start. So, I did search and found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g). It gives me a very brief idea about setting up vim.

I am still confused about the tools (vim or macvim), vim plugins, pathogens and how to setup as VIM ide.

Experts, please help me by pointing me to the resources which can help me to understand and learn vim and unleash the power of vim as an IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend installing the [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) plugin.

Then, add the following bundles to your **vimrc** file. (after reading how to configure/use vundle)

```
Plugin 'klen/python-mode'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
```

Whenever you add things for plugins for vundle to manage, make sure to run `:BundleInstall` in a new vim instance.

You can check out each of those projects on github for their dependencies.  The only one I can think of off the top of my head is jedi-vim, which requires you to install jedi (`pip install jedi`)

**vim-surround** contains handle operators for surrounding delimiters (), [], "", {}. see `:help surround` after install for usage.

**vim-easymotion** is great for moving around the page.  see `:help easymotion`

I prefer the autocompletion of python with jedi-vim instead of rope completion that comes with python-mode.  Its much quicker and more expressive.  To disable rope completion in python-mode, add the following to your **vimrc** after all the vundle plugin initialization.

```
let g:pymode_rope_lookup_project = 0
let g:pymode_rope_completion = 0
let g:pymode_rope_complete_on_dot = 0
```

Other plugins I recommend are:

**kien/ctrlp.vim** searching for file names, and buffer management

**scrooloose/nerdtree** project file explorer

Comment: would love to hear from you!

Answer (score 0):

About a plugins - this will be very useful [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode)

Python-mode contains:

- PyLint/PyFlakes/Pep8/mccabe (a python source code analyzers)
- Rope (a python refactoring library)
- PyDoc (documentation generator and help system)
- Python syntax highlighting

and many other features. They all working out of box and provide a lot of options for configuration. For the more help see `:help pymode.txt`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Dave Hi there, good to see you on SO.

Comment: @DaveClemmer Yes, you're right - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful resources are:

[vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/)

[vimwikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Tutorial)

[Tutsplus resources list](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/25-vim-tutorials-screencasts-and-resources--net-14631)

[My personal notes](https://github.com/shinokada/vimnotes/wiki)

[Practical vim book](http://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim)